# TTransportException "Cannot read, Remote side has closed"

Tags: c#, thrift

Getting this error in my client written in C#. My server is in python. This is my first test program using thrift. Looks like my python server is running. Here is my client code. I am getting this error where I am calling "Client.add(2,3)"

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            var socket = new TSocket("localhost", 9089);
            var transport = new TBufferedTransport(socket);
            var protocol = new TBinaryProtocol(transport);
            var client = new CalculatorService.Client(protocol);
            transport.Open();
            if (transport.IsOpen)
            {
                //I am seeing this message
                Console.WriteLine("server is open for business");                    
            }
            Console.WriteLine(client.add(2, 3)); //this is the line that gives me the error
            transport.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are the log on the server side, did it receive the call? Are you using the binary protocol on each side?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: I would like to know that aswell :)

Answer (score 2):

Try using,

```
client.InputProtocol.Transport.Open();
```

Instead of,

```
transport.Open();
```

BTW My server was Java based

Comment: Care to explain the down vote? This is a solution that worked for me that's why I put it as an answer.

Comment: Removed due to edit. in .NET land this change has no impact on the operations as `client.InputProtocol.Transport` and `transport` point to the same object.